# Delete cases for pattern that requires searching multiple points in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list of lists (representing three solutions to an equation):

```
mylist={ {a[1]->0,a[2]->2,a[3]->4}  ,  {a[1]->0,a[2]->4,a[3]->0} ,  {a[1]->0,a[2]->3} }
```

I want to delete cases where BOTH a[1] and a[3] are zero, i.e., where both a[1]->0 and a[3]->0 feature. The desired output is

```
desiredoutput={ {a[1]->0,a[2]->2,a[3]->4}    ,  {a[1]->0,a[2]->3} }
```

where I wish to retain the solution {a[1]->0,a[2]->3} as a[3] is unspecified.

Comment: but your `desiredoutput[[2]]` doesn't contain `a[3]`

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. I want to consider the case where a[3] is not specified, in which case I retain the solution. I will add a clarifying comment to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Select[mylist, Not[ContainsAll[#, {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> 0}]] &]
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the most expressive solution is to use [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) with [`KeyValuePattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValuePattern.html):

```
DeleteCases[mylist, KeyValuePattern[{a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> 0}]]
(* {{a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 2, a[3] -> 4}, {a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 3}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DeleteCases[mylist, _?(MemberQ[a[1] -> 0][#] && 
     MemberQ[a[3] -> 0][#] &)]
```

Or

```
DeleteCases[mylist, _?(ContainsAll[#, {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> 0}] &)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `GroupBy` and `KeyDrop`:

```
Last@KeyDrop[GroupBy[mylist, TrueQ[ContainsAll[#, {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> 0}]] &], True]
(*{{a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 2, a[3] -> 4}, {a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 3}}*)
```

Or using `If`:

```
If[TrueQ[ContainsAll[#, {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> 0}]], Nothing, #] & /@ mylist
(*{{a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 2, a[3] -> 4}, {a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 3}}*)
```